# Label component won't delete with BackSpace - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, filter

I have a React Native App.
I have a TextInput that has Filter/Search logic and a simple FlatList.
Click inside the TextInput a dropdown menu of Filters appear.
I Select one Filter and it appears as a Label inside my TextInput.
Then I can search any text.

TextInput with filter options:

Select filter "rehab":

Search text "test" in filtered messages:

Now my issue is when I hit BACKSPACE text "test" is deleted but the label is not. Because for that label I have created a separate component (Label.js). In this component I have just added the styling that's it.

Code:

```
import Label from './Label.js';
  <Icon type='materialicons' name='search'  />.  //search icon
  { val === "" ? null :
  <Label val={this.state.val}> {val} </Label>.  //Label component I created
  }
  <TextInput                                  //TextInput
    value={value} 
    placeholder='Search Here...'
    onChangeText={(text)=>{this.handleSearch(text, true))}}  
    style={{ height: 40, flex: 1}}
    autoCapitalize='none'
    selectTextOnFocus={true}
  />
  <Icon type='materialicons' name='cancel' onPress={()=> {this.handleFilterIcon(false)}} />         // clear text icon
```

So the CLEAR icon above will clear the Label. Thats working fine.
But if the user wants to just delete that label using "BackSpace" then that will create an issue.
Can the Label component be deleted using BackSpace key??? Is it possible??

**Updated Issue:**
As per the answer below I changed my code. Facing another issue.
 Filter is stored in "val" state.
Text string entered is stored in "value" state.
Using 2 conditions: 1) if both val and value are not initial then initialise "value" only
2)if only val is not initial then clear out "val"
How do I integrate both together????
Basically everything should be delete-able with "Backspace" key.

```
this.handleClearText(){
setState({
 value: ""
})
}

this.handleClearFilter(){
setState({
 val: ""
})
}

<TextInput
onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
                      if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace' && val !== "" && value !== "") {
                        this.handleClearText();
                      } 
                      if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace' && val !== "") {
                        this.handleClearFilter();
                      } 
/>
```

Comment: will there be one label or multiple?

Comment: @Vaibhav only one at a time.

Comment: means you want to keep the text but remove the label...right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the label if the text is empty and if the user presses backspace in an empty text,

```
    <TextInput
      onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
        if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace' && value==='') {
     //set label state value as empty
        }
      }}
    />
```

And inside the label you can handle displaying empty values.
You can also add conditions like the label value not being empty.

Update for Edited Question

You can use a custom component like this, 
Here enter will create something similar to tag and backspace will keep deleting the text and when text is empty it will remove the label.

```
const CustomInput = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <Text
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'aqua',
          alignSelf: 'flex-start',
          marginHorizontal: 10,
        }}>
        {val}
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="text"
        value={text}
        onChangeText={(t) => setText(t)}
        onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
          if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace' && text === '') {
            setVal('');
          }
          if (nativeEvent.key === 'Enter' && text !== '') {
            setVal(text);
            setText('');
          }
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Why have you put the onpress to flatlist ?